# primeng splitbutton's menu doesnt appear on top of all the elements

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

my problem seemed simple to me, but anything I tried didnt work..
I use splitbutton in primeng, I put the splitbutton inside a td inside a table

```
    <td>
   <p-splitButton label="actions" [model]="buttonItems" dir="ltr"></p-splitButton>
    </td>
```

the result is

[image]

the menu goes under the table
I tried to change z-index but it didnt help
anything I tried I cant show the menu on top

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the "appendTo" property on that button as described in the docs here: https://primeng.org/splitbutton#api.splitbutton.props.appendTo

Try setting the property like so:

```
<td>
<p-splitButton appendTo="body" label="actions" [model]="buttonItems" dir="ltr"></p-splitButton>
</td>
```